# Ansible - Alter Registered Variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

How can I modify the a registered variable?

For Example, `azure_network_interface_info.networkinterfaces[0].ip_configurations` has `public_ip_allocation_method` which I'd like to change it to `Static` or `Dynamic`. Then use the `ip_configurations` array somewhere else after its been modified.

```yaml
  - name: Get facts for one network interface
    azure_rm_networkinterface_info:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      name: "{{ azure_vm_network_interface }}"
    register: azure_network_interface_info
```

Output of registered variable:

```json
                        "ip_configurations": [
                            {
                                "application_gateway_backend_address_pools": null,
                                "application_security_groups": null,
                                "load_balancer_backend_address_pools": null,
                                "name": "Ubuntu915",
                                "primary": true,
                                "private_ip_address": "10.0.0.5",
                                "private_ip_address_version": "IPv4",
                                "private_ip_allocation_method": "Dynamic",
                                "public_ip_address": "/subscriptions/123456789/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Ubuntu-915-test",
                                "public_ip_address_name": "/subscriptions/123456789/resourceGroups/test-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Ubuntu-915-test",
                                "public_ip_allocation_method": null
                            }
                        ],
```

Comment: Try using this as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974565/associative-array-update-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update variables in places, however, you could use [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html) to create an other data structure like

```yaml
updated.azure_network_interface_info
```

and use that one. It seems that one of the documentation examples covers exactly your use case.

**Documentation**

- [`update_fact` - Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html#examples)

**Further Q&A**

- [Associative array update in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974932/6771046)

  > *Ansible isn't able to "update" variables. You can only create new variables. In many cases you can get what you want by replacing your target variable with a new one*
- [Ansible `set_fact` doesn't change the variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134080/6771046)
- [How can I dynamically change an Ansible variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39072341/6771046)